# How to display the sum of the sum displayed in python

Tags: python

This is the code:

```
import csv
from tkinter import Text
import pandas as pd
from csv import DictReader
import numpy as np
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta
from datetime import datetime
import decimal
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, DAILY
from datetime import *
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import shutil
import csv

op=True

def float_range(start, stop, step):
  while start < stop:
    yield float(start)
    start += decimal.Decimal(step)
x = True
List=[]
s=0
y=0.0
z=0
df=''
while (x==True):
    t = str(input(">"))
    if (t == '0'):
        a = str(input("Date : "))
        b = float(input("Haudi Katai Paddy(40Kg,30Kg)Nob : "))
        c = float(input("Rate : "))
        d = float(input("Haudi Katai Rice(60Kg,50Kg)Nob : "))
        e = float(input("Rate : "))
        f = float(input("Paddy Loading(40Kg,30Kg)Nob : "))
        g = float(input("Rate : "))
        h = float(input("Rice Loading(60kg,50kg,40kg)Nob : "))
        i = float(input("Rate : "))
        j = float(input("Rice Loading(25kg)Nob : "))
        k = float(input("Rate : "))
        l = float(input("Polish Loading Nob : "))
        m = float(input("Rate : "))
        n = float(input("Rice Dhala Nob : "))
        o = float(input("Rate : "))
        p = float(input("Bundle Stack/Loading Nob : "))
        q = float(input("Rate : "))
        r = float(input("Advance (if any) : "))
        s = float(b*c+d*e+f*g+h*i+j*k+l*m+n*o+p*q-r)

        # List 
        List=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s]
        
        with open('Records.csv', 'a',newline='') as f_object:
            df = pd.read_csv('Records.csv')

            new_df = df.dropna()

            writer_object =csv.writer(f_object)
        
            writer_object.writerow(List)

    else :
        bd = str(input("Start Date : "))
        ed = str(input("End Date : "))
        pp = 0
        EN = ''
        D = ''
        X = 0.0
        data2 = pd.read_csv("Records.csv")
        data = pd.read_csv("Records.csv")
        data.set_index("Date", inplace = True)
        df = data.loc[bd:ed,['Sum','Advance']]
        print(df)
```

Please ignore random fumctions imports and variables.
This is the csv file:

```
Date,"Haudi Katai Paddy(40Kg,30Kg)Nob",rate,"Haudi Katai Rice(60Kg,50Kg)Nob",rate.1,"Paddy Loading(40Kg,30Kg)Nob",rate.2,"Rice Loading(60kg,50kg,40kg)Nob",rate.3,Rice Loading(25kg)Nob,rate.4,Polish Loading Nob,rate.5,Rice Dhala Nob,rate.6,Bundle Stack/Loading Nob,rate.7,Advance,Sum,2
34,34.0,43.0,43.0,43.0,43.0,43.0,43.0,43.0,43.0,43.0,43.0,43.0,43.0,43.0,43.0,43.0,43.0,14362.0,
43,43.0,43.0,43.0,43.0,43.0,43.0,43.0,43.0,43.0,43.0,43.0,43.0,43.0,43.0,43.0,43.0,433.0,14359.0,
10-06-2021,224.0,2442.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,559314.0,
11-06-2021,24.0,24.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,12882.0,
12-06-2021,42.0,2442.0,24.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,114114.0,
13-06-2021,24.0,24.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,24.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,42.0,24.0,42.0,24.0,11388.0,
2021/06/11,23.0,23.0,23.0,23.0,23.0,23.0,3.0,223.0,32.0,23.0,23.0,23.0,23.0,23.0,32.0,32.0,23.0,5051.0,
2021/06/12,32.0,32.0,32.0,23.0,32.0,23.0,23.0,32.0,32.0,32.0,32.0,32.0,23.0,23.0,32.0,32.0,23.0,6810.0,
2021/06/13,2.0,32.0,23.0,23.0,23.0,32.0,23.0,32.0,32.0,32.0,32.0,3.0,23.0,32.0,32.0,23.0,23.0,4634.0,
2021-06-15,434.0,43.0,54.0,56.0,4.0,46.0,57.0,57.0,75.0,5.0,32.0,35.0,56.0,57.0,35.0,65.0,42.0,32039.0,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,450
```

This is the output:

```
>2
Start Date : 10-06-2021
End Date : 13-06-2021
                 Sum  Advance
Date
10-06-2021  559314.0     42.0
11-06-2021   12882.0     42.0
12-06-2021  114114.0     42.0
13-06-2021   11388.0     24.0
>
```

OK I am having an issue that as u can see in the output Sum and Advance is printed for the specific dates entered.The sum printed (559314.0,12882.0,114114.0 and 11388.0).I want that the sum of these numbers should be printed below these numbers and same with advance.
Then the Total sum should be subtracted from Total advance.And then it should be printed.
I am facing this issue from last week i tried writing some if conditions but that also didnt work.
Please help solving this problem.

Thank You

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure I understand: "How to display the sum of the sum"... is a sum of a sum not what you want? Could you please give us an example of your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to sum a dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html)

```
df['Sum'].sum()
```

Comment: Start Date : 10-06-2021
End Date : 13-06-2021 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/DELL/Documents/Python/sanmat3.py", line 77, in <module>
    df.sum.sum()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'sum'

Comment: In the output, you have a table with the following columns: Date(index), Sum, Advance. Select the "Sum" column and apply sum() on it. You can put this right before your print., without modifying the code.

Comment: Sir It is working now this code is showing error because of the second statement u have written